# ImageMagick only converts first page of pdf when using streams

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick

### Question

When I use ImageMagick to convert a pdf by reading the entire file into memory, it converts the PDF into 6 page images (as desired). When I attempt the same using the streaming interface, it only converts the first page, and none of the others. How do I get the streaming version of this code to convert the entire pdf?

### Code

```
import {createReadStream, createWriteStream} from 'fs'
const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true })

const readStream = createReadStream(__dirname + '/assets/lockheed-short.pdf')
const writeStream = createWriteStream(__dirname + '/temp/lockheed-short.png')

gm(__dirname + '/assets/lockheed-short.pdf')
  .setFormat('png')
  .write(__dirname + '/temp/lockheed-short.png', (err) => {
    err && console.error(err)
  }) // converts the whole pdf like I want!

gm(readStream)
  .stream('png')
  .pipe(writeStream) // converts only the first page - why??
```

### Environment

Using GhostScript 9.26 and ImageMagick 7.0.8-49

I don't see any error output from this, but I'm relatively unfamiliar with streams.

Comment: There is no version 9.6 of Ghostscript, teh current version is 9.27, we haven't reached the .6 level yet. This isn't a Ghostscript question either so I've removed that tag.

Comment: @KenS - I missed the 2 before the 6. I'll correct that. The reason I think GhostScript is related is that it's used to read the pdf behind ImageMagick. I believe what I need is to know when a page ends in the stream, and pipe that to a new writable. Any insight on how to tell when there's a new page?

Comment: Certainly Ghostscript does the rendering of PDF files for ImageMagick (or more precisely, the PDF delegate does, but that's normally Ghostscript). Although Ghostscript is involved, that's totally true, this isn't a question (IMO) that actually relates to Ghostscript. You say that ImageMaigck behaves differently when using the stream interface to using memory, so it seems to me that its IM behaving differently here, not GS. FWIW, there's no possible way that Ghostscript is handling this in memory, if you send the PDF file on stdin, then it gets written to a temp file and rendered from there.

Comment: So that being the case, you can't tell when a page ends 'in the stream', and indeed, because PDF files store objects non-seuqntially in the file, its basiclaly not possible to render a PDF file from a non-seekablle source. Its possible IM is sending the file to GS 'n' times where 'n' is the number of pages, and asking for each page to be rendered in turn, but more likely its sending the file and asking for all the pages to be rendered. What IM does with them after that, I have no idea I'm afraid.

Comment: I can't read all those parentheses all over the place in Javascript, but I know you can get individual pages of a PDF rasterised with **ImageMagick** by passing the desired page number in square brackets directly after the PDF filename. So if you want the 3rd page, starting from page 0, you would run `convert document.pdf[2] result.png` if that helps.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes that's true! Unfortunately, since I'm trying to accomplish this entire bit through streams (stream down a file from S3, convert all pages, stream contents to new bucket in S3), I don't have the ability to get just one page at a time.

Comment: @KenS thanks for looking at this again